# How to show a double formatted as a price in a textview in android

Tags: android, string, textview

I want to show in a textView a price value like: 12,199.99 in a textview in Android. but I have the value stored in a double variable (12199.99). Is there any way to show that double in the textview in the format I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to format it using the phone's locale with 2 decimals do like this:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
String formattedValue = decimalFormat.format(yourDoubleValue);
yourTextView.setText(formattedValue);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `BigDecimal` for it, for example

```
public static BigDecimal doubleToScale(double d, int scale){
        return new BigDecimal(d).setScale(scale, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
}
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). More documentation on the formatting options can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).